# How to send parameter containing "%" in a REST ( C # WCF ) service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soapui

I have this function that returns the code of a user who was authenticated correctly

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
           UriTemplate = "67g09k2r8/{usu}/{pas}", 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
int Login(String usu, String pas);
```

when I perform the tests from SoapUI works well . Here a test

[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hKyQ.png)

but when I try with a parameter that contains the character "%" I get this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLqek.png)

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Post code or text where possible, not images.  Images reduce the ability to search and find duplicate questions.

Comment: I think you need to use URL encoding.  %25 is the escape sequence for `%`. So for your test, it would be `http://localhost:89/servicioWCF/javier/pas%25w_4`

Comment: I can safely assume that you're not using a username and password like this. This is just a test, right? You'll never do it that way.

Comment: Hi Tim, try but I get the same error, is there any other option?

Comment: Thomas , is only a test , actually that should send as post , but I'm doing tests with GET

Comment: SoapUI has a known bug that it does not encode URLs properly. Has been there since sometime in version 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

% sign is used for encoding in urls. It must be followed by 2 hexadecimal digits which denote the character code. Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

If you actually want to send "%" sign in the url, you have to encode it by entering "%25".

Comment: Hi pkmiec, try but I get the same error, is there any other option?

Comment: Please post the error detalis.. It should be at least minimally different

Answer (score 0):

the temporary solution was to change the POST method, with that I was solved.

The new function:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "67g09k2r8", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int Login(String usu, String pas);
```